# How do I make a shape key for blink into wink?

Tags: shape-keys

I just spent a lot of time making my character blink forgetting that I should have done only one eye and then mirror it.

Do I have to start over or is there a trick to make only one eye blink?

Comment: Assign a vertex group to the shape key that limits it only for half the face. Duplicate the shape key and  assign opposite vertex group for the other eye.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny Assign a vertex group to the shape key that limits it only for half the face. I don't have a clue how to do such a thing.

Comment: Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iks5.png

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I didn’t know you could do that - never noticed the option. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below.

[image]

In the part where I go into edit mode, the vertices were already selected, but you may have to go into Wireframe view to select the overlapping vertices before doing *Blend from Shape*

Also notice in the command list under **Shape Keys** there is a *Mirror Shape Key*. You could redo the same steps for *wink.L* and mirror it instead of *Blend from Shape* to create *wink.R*

Comment: Could you please update this answer for 2.80, @Timo?

Comment: [ F3 ] type Blend from shape dialog box appears in lower corner. I have yet to understand how the one works with its new feature of choosing the key... for now.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was 
Duplicate the head twice.
Deleted the original head.
Divided the heads down the middle, kept one of the opposite halves of each.
One side I kept the blink key the other I deleted all shape keys.
I selected one of the head's joining seam and move it just enough to see it separated from the other.
I joined them as one CTRL-J
I then Selected both joining seams and did Bridge edge loops.
I placed the 3D cursor to center.
Set pivot/scale to cursor.
I did scale X=0 overlapping both edges.
Then I did a clean up> remove doubles.
That is still simpler than starting over.